# TypeORM: How ownership side works?

Tags: sql, typescript, foreign-keys, relational-database, typeorm

Suppose we have two models `Profile` and `User`:

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./User";

@Entity()
export class Profile {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    
    @Column()
    gender: string;
    
    @Column()
    photo: string;
    
    @OneToOne(() => User, user => user.profile) // specify inverse side as a second parameter
    user: User;
    
}
```

```js
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, OneToOne, JoinColumn} from "typeorm";
import {Profile} from "./Profile";

@Entity()
export class User {
    
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
    
    @Column()
    name: string;
    
    @OneToOne(() => Profile, profile => profile.user) // specify inverse side as a second parameter
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;
    
}
```

I want have bi-directional relation between these two models and it works, I can find `Profile` from `User` and vice versa. However when I ran `SHOW CREATE TABLE profile` there was no reference whatsoever to `User` model! Then how does it work? How can I find join `User` from `Profile` side?

Does it affect the performance which side is the owner? If not, What is the point of thinking about which side to put `@joinColumn`?

Answer (score 3):

As you found, the User definition in the database has no reference to Profile because there is no `@JoinColumn` on the User Table. It is the `@JoinColumn` that defines the foreign-key relationship in the database. The `@OneToOne` is used my TypeOrm to generate metadata and queries, but it does not affect the database schema.

Note: You can only have `@JoinColumn` on one side of the relation.

If it is a true one-to-one relationship, it does not matter which side you put the `@JoinColumn`.

If it's possible to have a Profile row without a matching User row, the `@JoinColumn` has to be on User.